# meta-command - need help with expansion

Tags: macros, expansion

To enforce labeling regulations in a document to be edited by ~50 users (imported subdocuments) i have to re-redine the existing document structuring commands part, chapter, etc to follow a predefined labeling scheme (prefixing with hierarchy level to avoid collisions).

As examples speak more than words, here my current definition for chapter (omitting details). Basically, both `\chapter` and `\chapter*` are extended with an optional parameter used to define a label which is automatically prefixed by "`chap:`", reusing the old `\chapter` command. Additionally, a command for creating references is defined where short vs. long reference text is chosen via the boolean variable `\iflongrefs`.

```
\RequirePackage{letltxmacro}
\RequirePackage{xargs}

\newcommand*\section@namelong{Section}%
\newcommand*\section@nameshort{Sect.}%
\newcommand*\section@prefix{sect}%

\LetLtxMacro{\section@old}{\section}%
\renewcommand\section{\@ifstar \section@star \section@nostar}%
\newcommandx*\section@nostar[3][1=,3=]{%
    \ifx &#1&%
        \section@old{#2}%
    \else%
        \section@old[#1]{#2}%
    \fi%
    \ifx &#3&%
    \else%
        \label{\section@prefix:#3}%
    \fi%
}%
\newcommandx*\section@star[2][2=]{%
    \section@old*{#1}%
    \ifx &#2&%
    \else%
        \label{\section@prefix:#2}%
    \fi%
}%

\newcommand*\sectionref[1]{
    \iflongrefs
        \section@namelong~\ref{\section@prefix:#1}
    \else
        \section@nameshort\,\ref{\section@prefix:#1}
    \fi
}
```

Now, I need similar definitions for part, subsection, etc... Of course I can copy & paste this, replacing `\section@XXX` with `\part@XXX` etc accordingly. However I'd prefer a more elegant solution, such as a "higher-order command" `\extend` encapsulating the (re)definitions. A call to `\extend` for chapters should look like the line given below, and produce all the code seen above.

```
\extend{section}{Section}{Sect.}{sect}
```

How can I make this work? Reading through various forum posts I feel `\expandafter` is the way to go, but I did not understand the examples enough to get it working for me. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of **etoolbox** (but only for convenience): just change all `\section` into `#1`, but using `\csdef` and `\csuse`; the important thing is to refer to arguments of macros defined inside the metamacro by doubling `#` symbols.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{xargs}

\newif\iflongrefs

\newcommand{\extend}[4]{%
  \csdef{#1@namelong}{#2}%
  \csdef{#1@nameshort}{#3}%
  \csdef{#1@prefix}{#4}%
  \csletcs{#1@old}{#1}%
  \csdef{#1}{\@ifstar{\csuse{#1@star}}{\csuse{#1@nostar}}}%
  \expandafter\newcommandx\expandafter*\csname#1@nostar\endcsname[3][1=,3=]{%
    \ifx &##1&%
        \csuse{#1@old}{##2}%
    \else
        \csuse{#1@old}[##1]{##2}%
    \fi
    \ifx &##3&%
    \else
      \label{\csuse{#1@prefix}:##3}%
    \fi
  }%
  \expandafter\newcommandx\expandafter*\csname#1@star\endcsname[2][2=]{%
    \csuse{#1@old}*{##1}%
    \ifx &##2&%
    \else
      \label{\csuse{#1@prefix}:##2}%
    \fi
  }
  \csdef{#1ref}##1{%
    \iflongrefs
        \csuse{#1@namelong}~\ref{\csuse{#1@prefix}:##1}%
    \else
        \csuse{#1@nameshort}\,\ref{\csuse{#1@prefix}:##1}%
    \fi
  }%
}
\makeatother

\extend{section}{Section}{Sect.}{sect}
\extend{subsection}{Subection}{Subsect.}{subsect}

\begin{document}

\section{abc}

\section[aaa]{abc}[def]


\sectionref{def}

{\longrefstrue\sectionref{def}}

\subsection[uuu]{vvv}[www]

\subsectionref{www}

\end{document}
```

Note that `\LetLtxMacro` is not necessary, as `\section` and friends are *not* defined to have optional arguments.

### Added – xparse version

Instead of **xargs** you may want to use the modern **xparse** package:

```
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage[log-declarations = false]{xparse}

\newcommand{\extend}[4]{%
  \csdef{#1@namelong}{#2}%
  \csdef{#1@nameshort}{#3}%
  \csdef{#1@prefix}{#4}%
  \csletcs{#1@old}{#1}%
  \expandafter\DeclareDocumentCommand\csname#1\endcsname{s o m o}{
    \IfBooleanTF{##1}
      {\csuse{#1@old}*{##3}
%       \IfNoValueTF{##4}
%         {}
%         {\label{\csuse{#1@prefix}:##4}}
      }
      {\IfNoValueTF{##2}
         {\csuse{#1@old}{##3}}
         {\csuse{#1@old}[##2]{##3}}
       \IfNoValueTF{##4}
         {}
         {\label{\csuse{#1@prefix}:##4}}
      }
  }
  \expandafter\DeclareDocumentCommand\csname#1ref\endcsname{m}{
    \iflongrefs
        \csuse{#1@namelong}~\ref{\csuse{#1@prefix}:##1}
    \else
        \csuse{#1@nameshort}\,\ref{\csuse{#1@prefix}:##1}
    \fi
  }%
}
```

The three commented lines are because it's not clear what's the purpose of a label to a `\section*` command.

Comment: Really works like a charm - thank you so much! Btw I kept the lines you commented out as I extended the code to also build \XXXpageref commands which can definitely make sense for unnumbered elements as well.